# An exception occurred during a WebClient request(Access to the path 'E:\Zipfils\Backups\Hyderabad' is denied.)

Tags: c#, windows, webclient

I am using following code for download ZIP file from a Directory(like "hedrabad") from ftp server.

try {

```
            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Procedures.ftpurl);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Procedures.ftpuser, Procedures.ftpPassword);
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            List<string> directories = new List<string>();

            string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                directories.Add(line);
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
            streamReader.Close();

            using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
            {
                ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Procedures.ftpuser, Procedures.ftpPassword);

                for (int i = 0; i <= directories.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    //if (directories[i].Contains("."))
                    //{
                    if (directories[i].ToString() == "Hyderabad")
                    {
                        log.Info("File Downloding  Start : " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm ss"));
                        if (!Directory.Exists(OGSync.FTPPath + "\\Backups\\" + directories[i].ToString()))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(OGSync.FTPPath + "\\Backups\\" + directories[i].ToString());
                        }
                        //string path = Procedures.ftpurl;
                        string path = Procedures.ftpurl + directories[i].ToString();
                        string trnsfrpth = OGSync.FTPPath + "Backups\\" + directories[i].ToString();

                        //string trnsfrpth = @"E:\\Test\" + directories[i].ToString();
                        ftpClient.DownloadFile(path, trnsfrpth);
                        //ftpClient.DownloadFile(path, @"C:\file.zip");
                    }
                    // }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I am getting following error I have tried but did not get resolved.please any can give some idea how to resolve this.

Exception :  Access to the path 'E:\Zipfils\Backups\Hyderabad' is denied.

Inner Exception :     Access to the path 'E:\Zipfils\Backups\Hyderabad' is denied.

StackTrace:     at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile(Uri address, String fileName)  at OGServerSync.ServerSync.Downloadfile() in E:\Modular Code and Installer\OGServerSync\OGServerSync\ServerSync.cs:line 64

Message:  An exception occurred during a WebClient request.

Comment: Looks like you’re tying to download the directory itself and not the files it contains

Comment: yes there is multiple files in the directory so how we can download files